# How to turn off message like 'Too many levels of symbolic links' in find command?

Tags: unix

How too turn off these messages from find unix command:
 1. Too many levels of symbolic links
 2. is part of a loop in the directory hierarchy; we have already visited the directory to which it points

Is there some option in find command to turn these off ?
Shell (sh, bash) redirection to stderr works (find . -follow  -name fasd 2> /dev/null).

**Sample logs**

$ find . -follow  -name fasd
find: ./ctags/latest/RHEL4.0-1H2006-x86_64: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: Symbolic link `./doxygen/v1.3.9.1/2.4.18-5' is part of a loop in the directory hierarchy; we have already visited the directory to which it points
find: ./make/v4.0/RHEL5.0-2010-x86_64: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: redirect all standard errors to/dev/null.

Comment: redirect works. but there should be some find options also to do it.

Comment: if you are confident then why dont you use it?

Comment: I use tcsh in which redirecting only error is not so easy as in sh, bash.

Comment: @DeepakY Well, there are no such option in find.

Comment: /bin/sh  should exist on all POSIX systems.  On POSIX-compliant systems it is a "POSIX shell", not tcsh or csh.  Redirection in that shell is simple.  Consider changing the shebang to:   !#/bin/sh